# Runtime Error 53 "File Not Found" from LotusScript agent (SOLVED)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, hcl-notes

For unknown reasons a server-side LotusScript agent is throwing Error 53 "File not found" while trying to read the physical file size of an existing mail archive file. Situation is as follows:

the LS agent is looping all files in a given directory "\archive" right below the server's "\Data" dir. The Server in question is Domino 10.0.1 running on a Windows 2016 Server.
The LS code is looping the directory looking for database files whose names follow a given pattern like "a_*EmployeeID*.nsf". If a DB's filename fits the pattern the code scans the server's names.nsf for the archive owner using the *EmployeeID* from the filename. If no person doc for that ID is found the code tries to read the db's physical file size using `FileLen(filePath & FileName)`. Then the resulting data (filepath + file size) + EmployeeID are written to a report file on disk. Files that don't follow the pattern are also at least written back to the report. The idea behind that agent is to find "orphaned" or misplaced databases.

For ~80% of the files scanned this works fine, the records with exact file sizes are written to the report. But for the other ~20% runtime `error 53 "File not found"` pulls up. In those case the record just contains the file path/name + EmployeeID (if available) + "-1" for the file size. Because the file obviously do exist I assume that this is an access or security problem.

The agent is signed with an admin ID having maximum access rights on both the server and the archive files in question (the ID by policy has Manager access in the dbs' ACLs).
The agent's security settings are set to level 3 (unrestricted access with full admin rights) because I first had signed the agent with an ID having Full Admin Access on the server (same result as with the now used ID).

Comparing the databases' ACLs  I can't find any differences between those that "work" and the ones that don't. What I see, though, is that it's apparently always the same databases that are throwing this error, so this isn't a random problem.

For completeness here are the crucial parts of the agent code:

```
sFileName = Dir$(sPath & "*.nsf")
Do Until sFileName = ""
    iCount = iCount + 1
    sEmpid = "" 'reset
    lSizeArc = 0 'reset
    dblSizeArc = 0 'reset
    sSizeArcFmt = "" 'reset
    If(sFileName Like sPattern) Then
        sEmpid = Left(Right(sFileName, Len(sFileName) - 2), 6)
        Set vec = vwEgid.Getallentriesbykey(sEmpid, True)
        If(vec.count = 0) Then
            On Error 53 Resume Next 'Error 53 ("File not found")
            lSizeArc = FileLen(sPath & sFilename)
            If(Err = 53) Then
                lSizeArc = -1
                sSizeArcFmt = "-1 (no size available)"
                Err = 0
            Else
                dblSizeArc = Round((lSizeArc / 1024 / 1024), 3)
                sSizeArcFmt = Format$(dblSizeArc, "0.000") & " MB"
            End If
            Print #iFileNum,_
                "ORPHANED_ARCHIVE;" & sEmpid & ";" & sFileName & ";" & sSizeArcFmt
        End If
    Else
        On Error 53 Resume Next 'Error 53 ("File not found") 
        lSizeArc = FileLen(sPath & sFilename)
        If(Err = 53) Then
            lSizeArc = -1
            sSizeArcFmt = "-1 (no size available)"
            Err = 0
        Else
            dblSizeArc = Round((lSizeArc / 1024 / 1024), 3)
            sSizeArcFmt = Format$(dblSizeArc, "0.000") & " MB"
        End If
        Print #iFileNum,_
            "BAD_FILE_PATTERN;NO_EGID;" & sFilename & ";" & sSizeArcFmt
    End If
    sFileName = Dir$() 'next file
Loop
```

Before I start moving in a different direction like looking into using Windows shell or .dll commands I'd really like to understand why in some cases the code insists that some of the files looked at cannot be "found".

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2021-05-19**

So finally I found the solution to that weirdness (and it's not a compliment to my programming skills, I admit):
looking again at the files that are throwing error 53 I realized that they all are rather big, > 2.1 GB to be exact. So I have to admit that I made a stupid programming error: assigning a value that size to a LONG variable won't work, of course. Stupid amateur error ...
(But then why doesn't the code throw the proper error telling the value exceeds the limits, as it usually does?)
Anyways, so I changed the variable to be a DOUBLE.
But: result is still the same, though >> error 53.
Then again looking at Designer help I found this small note:

> FileLen returns a Long value

In other words: FileLen itself cannot handle files that size, and that error apparently is thrown before the interpreter finds out about my bad coding.
In other words: no way to solve my problem that way. Back to @TorstenLink's comment: I'll use his method now

Extremely strange error message, still, I would say...

Thanks to everyone helping me think ;)

Comment: Domino locks databases within its access for access outside of Domino. I'd never try to get such information from the filesystem... Why not use NotesDBDirectory?

Comment: Yep, using NotesDBDirectory had been my original plan. But then I realized that this method has 2 week spots: - #1 looping this object I don't have any control over the folders to loop. The server in question holds several ten thousand databases, but I'm only interested in the ones below the \archive folder, it's always the entire server. - #2 with this object I can only access the database object. I have to look at it if it is stored in the right folder, and then whether its file name follow the given pattern. And if both is the case I have to open the Database in order to look for its size

Comment: Does it have anything to do with special characters in the file name?

Comment: NotesDBDirectory is a quite fast object. Cycling through thousands of databases is just a few seconds unless you open the database (NotesDatabase- Objects obtained via NotesDBDirectory are not open, you need to call db.Open( "", "" ) for the databases that you are interested in). And the filepath can be read from the closed object: `If Left( db.FilePath , 8 ) = "archive\" then`. This will be very fast as you only need to really open the files in the right path...

Comment: @Duston - shouldn't be a prob. The pattern is basically "a_EmpID.nsf", where EmpId is 6 characters starting with "E", followed by a 2nd simple ASCII char (usually A through E), followed by a 4 digit number. But it still is a good idea to have a real close look - maybe there's some "invisible" special char. I'll check that

Comment: @TorstenLink - maybe you're right, I'll think about it. Still this really bugs me because that error simply doesn't make any sense here; it is a "dead" archive server, no users activity should be involved. And even if that was the case, why should it always be the same databases causing trouble, in the course of several days?

Comment: @TorstenLink - added an update to my post - and I have to apologize for not really going along with your recommendation. Because it's working nicely - if you feel like it then repeat as an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LotusScript is probably making a call to a 32 bit WinAPI to obtain the file-length and this call will be returning a unsigned 32 bit value, for a maximum file size of ~4.2Gb. However, LS doesn't support unsigned 32 bit values, only signed, so any value returned over 2.1Gb is represented by a negative value.

You can take the absolute value of the negative value and put it in a currency or single/float, and add 2.1Gb to get a file-size up to 4.2Gb, but no bigger, since the API call won't be returning a bigger number and therefore, the API call probably doesn't consider this an error and LS hasn't technically 'overflowed' generating a size error.

Alternatively, if you consider any size over say 1Gb as 'reportable' just look for values that are either +ve and > 1gb or < 0 as any negative value means 'big'. I'm guessing the exact file size isn't that important to you.

Comment: Very interesting thought, indeed, and it is very likely that you are right with your assumptions. Thanks for sharing you thoughts! - It's been close to a year that I had to solve this. Just looked it up: I finally solved it using the NotesDbDirectory object as was recommended by @Tode in his comment above. In the resulting reports I still see quite a few entries returning a db size of "-1". The customer and me finally decided that this is enough information as it is obvious that those dbs are *big*, without knowing the reason for the "-1" output. Now I think I know, thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 1):

Since you only READ from disk: DIR and FileLen, you should'nt suffer from Domino LOCK on the file (but don't try to write !)

I suggest you to change your code in order to determine where it falls and on which files:

```
f(vec.count = 0) Then
        placeInCode = 1 'declare this before as int
        On Error 53 Resume goto handelError'Error 53 ("File not found")
```

in the second part, affect placeInCode = 2

then declare a

```
handelError:
    print "we got error 53 on " & sPath & sFilename & " for the " & placeInCode & " part"
    resume next
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I know already on which file the code "fails": on error 53 I resume then write the filename to my report

Comment: According to your filter in DIR, all your files are *.nsf, so it doesn't seems to be relevant but take a look at https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/596230-filecopy-results-runtime-error-53-file-not-found.

Comment: Interesting indeed, thanks for the link. I don't feel it's related, but then I also feel that my code should work the way it is :D Still it might be good idea to try the same from a VB / VBA script